# Why continuous paths implies smooth path on the manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

On the page 32 of Lee's book *Manifolds and differential geometry*, he writes:

> In the definition of path connectedness..., we used *continuous*
>   paths, but it is not hard to show that if two points on a smooth
>   manifold can be connected by a continuous path, then they can be
>   connected by a smooth path.

I do not quite understand.

First of all, what does a path being smooth mean? A path on a manifold is a function:
$$
p:[0,1]\rightarrow M
$$

I think to be *continuous* is in the topological sense.

But what does *smooth* mean? Is it in the diffeomorphic sense?

Do we regard $[0,1]$ as a set in the manifold $\mathbb{R}$ and applying the definition of smoothness of function between manifolds?

After all, I wonder how to prove this statement.

Comment: In down-to-earth terms it means that the derivative $p^\prime(t)$ exists at every $t\in(0,1)$. Then, the claim is that every continouous path in a smooth manifold can be deformed to a smooth map. This results from a Smoothing Lemma which is usually given for granted in any graduate course on the subject ... :)

Comment: ..all right.. I will take it for granted too..:)

Comment: @AndreaMori Could you give any reference to the smoothing lemma?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: it's more than 30 years since I studied these topics and I am not even sure about what are the standard basic references nowadays. I suppose that any text covering the basics of analysis on maniflds would do.